# Latest Migration to Heroku doesn't seem to be working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migration

In my latest commit, I added a boolean column called "accepted" to a table/model named Submissions. It migrated fine in my test and development environments, but when I pushed it to Heroku, it doesn't seem to work. After pushing I used:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

This was the output:

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.2430
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
** [NewRelic][01/29/13 23:23:10 +0000 0d3d429d-5437-42d0-9c57-e15606717231 (2)] INFO : Starting the New Relic Agent.
** [NewRelic][01/29/13 23:23:10 +0000 0d3d429d-5437-42d0-9c57-e15606717231 (2)] INFO : Environment: production
** [NewRelic][01/29/13 23:23:10 +0000 0d3d429d-5437-42d0-9c57-e15606717231 (2)] INFO : Dispatcher: thin
** [NewRelic][01/29/13 23:23:10 +0000 0d3d429d-5437-42d0-9c57-e15606717231 (2)] INFO : Application: chicagoimprovfestival
** [NewRelic][01/29/13 23:23:10 +0000 0d3d429d-5437-42d0-9c57-e15606717231 (2)] INFO : Installing ActiveRecord instrumentation
** [NewRelic][01/29/13 23:23:10 +0000 0d3d429d-5437-42d0-9c57-e15606717231 (2)] INFO : Installing Net instrumentation
** [NewRelic][01/29/13 23:23:10 +0000 0d3d429d-5437-42d0-9c57-e15606717231 (2)] INFO : Installing Rails 3 Controller instrumentation
** [NewRelic][01/29/13 23:23:10 +0000 0d3d429d-5437-42d0-9c57-e15606717231 (2)] INFO : Installing Rails 3.1/3.2 view instrumentation
** [NewRelic][01/29/13 23:23:10 +0000 0d3d429d-5437-42d0-9c57-e15606717231 (2)] INFO : Installing Rails3 Error instrumentation
** [NewRelic][01/29/13 23:23:10 +0000 0d3d429d-5437-42d0-9c57-e15606717231 (2)] INFO : Finished instrumentation
** [NewRelic][01/29/13 23:23:12 +0000 0d3d429d-5437-42d0-9c57-e15606717231 (2)] INFO : Starting Agent shutdown
```

In the logs I get this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `accepted' for #<Submission:0x00000005e71080>):
```

Of course I do not get an error like that in development. Any suggestion? Is my migration failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrations didn't get added to the commit. I fixed it and now it seems to be working.